# Handling a big Excel File

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I am managing an Excel data file (Excel 2010) which contains more than 400,000 rows and 55 columns.

It is impossible to work with a Pivot table: I get a message that Excel does not have enough resources (I can't play with the pivot / refresh etc.)

I also tried to use the "Power Pivot", but didn't succeed uploading the file to the power pivot: I get all kinds of errors (Syntax errors etc...)

Anyone has an idea how can that be solved?

Comment: As of 2007, Excel is supposed to handle upwards of a million rows...of course, this is system dependent.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the data should be in a database.

Comment: Yep, get an MS Access database going, and import your spreadsheet.